# tails memory wiping fails? / cannot use bridge

Tags: tails

About Tails,

1.when I used it before,***(asterisk)was shown on screen one after another during memory wiping before shutting down.
But with latest version 2.1,’*’ never appears during memory wiping.
Does this mean memory wiping fails?

2.I’m testing to use bridge (in preparation for using public wifi which may not connect to Tor network).
I go to https://bridges.torproject.org/ , get obfs4 bridges and paste them from Tails Greeter(configure bridge settings),but it doesn’t work.
Here is the log(partially omitted)
[NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.(53 same msgs)
[NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.(3 same msgs)
[NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:****(4 msgs / port numbers differ)
[NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/etc/tor/torrc.orig.1" 
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
[NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
[WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to ***.***.***.***:**** ("general SOCKS server failure") 
[NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:****
[NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:****(9msgs / port numbers differ)
[NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
[NOTICE] Closing old Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:****
[NOTICE] Closing old DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:****

I tried in vain with live dvd,live usb, and inside virtualbox.
But with Tbb on ubuntu16.4,it does work,using the same bridges.
Why?

Comment: 1. It should be working, the display can corrupt (as it notes). If it doesn't reset then that suggests memory wiping failed. 2. The proxy fail suggests there are network connectivity errors.

Comment: Thank you for advice.About bridge,I just configured in accordance with Tails Greeter and never changed anything else.

Comment: Right, so you're if using obfs4 the bridgeline you enter should look something like `obfs4 1.2.3.4:5678 01235... cert=AaBbCcDd... iat-mode=0`, right?

Comment: Thank you again.Yes.Pasted text on Network Settings window is “obfs4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:nnnnn... iat-mode=0”.Any of the parameters(obfs4,ip,port,fingerprint,cert,iat-mode) are not omitted.
I tried with another pc but result was the same.
But I found tails in virtualbox went well using bridge about which I wrote the wrong information above(I wrote failed).In virtualbox,tails doesn't use wifi connection.(and meaningless for preparation of using public wifi) 
But Whichever I use(usb or virtualbox+iso),I can use unsafe browser and can go to https://bridges.torproject.org to get bridges.

Comment: Considering being able to use unsafebrowser,my wifi router is incompatible with bridge?
Without using bridge, of course I can connect to Tor network with tails at home.(I'm testing in preparation for using public wifi which may not connect to Tor Network.)
If I try some more times and can't do safely and easily then I will give it up.
Thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: The Tor Browser that works with those bridges on Ubuntu 16.04, does it work with a completely new copy of Tor Browser? The bridge is failing fetching some directory information, I wonder if Tor Browser has this cached already and is skipping it, but Tails cannot.

Answer (score 0):

`[WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to XXX` - are you sure that there's no incorrect proxy configuration in your TAILS? It seems to be so

Comment: Thank you for advice.About bridge,I just configured in accordance with Tails Greeter and never changed anything else.

Comment: Try to make the whole config in torrc text file and run Tor from a command line with the config - will it help? We need to eliminate the risk of GUI misbehaving

Comment: Thank you again.
But it seems too difficult for me to configure torrc and run Tor from a command line every time I launch tails.
If I try some more times and can't do safely and easily then I will give it up.
Thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: The behaviour of the GUI you're asking about is wrong, but sometimes it happens - even the Vidalia(a *very decent* GUI for Tor) misbehaved when it was wearing it's kiddy pants, so I think it will be fixed in a future releases of Tails. As for me - I'm using Linux kernel as a host for VM's where some "torified" apps live *separately* from each other and I'm launching Tor on the host and routing the traffic. I can give you full tor starting scripts and configs for Linux if you need. And if you will PM me with a bridge data - I'll insert it too. My facebook contacts are in my profile